# Do I need to give my electron icon padding?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I've set my electron app icon by converting a 2014x1024 png to icns using this: https://github.com/bitboss-ca/png2icns

However, my icon looks every so slightly bigger than all the others in the "taskbar" on macOS (comes up when you cmd-tab).

Do I need to give my icon some sort of padding or something? How can I make it the same dimensions as other icons?

There doesn't seem to be any guidance on this, only on file formats and ideal dimensions (which I've adhered to already).

Comment: Seems slightly off-topic :P Have you seen [this](https://www.electron.build/icons)?

Comment: @FelixD. Yes. My icon was 1024x1024 (so adheres to `at least 512x512`) and is called icon.icns and was in the `buildResources` directory. Still looks too big when compared with, for eg, the Chrome icon in the task switcher on macOS. Hence the question :P.

Comment: @ndtreviv I've run into the exact same issue. Have you figured out a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @Vishnu I gave it padding 